# Use of diff_drive_controller to simulate a differential drive in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, ros-control, diff-drive-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did anybody manage to use **diff_drive_controller** in to simulate a **differential drive** in Gazebo**?
Theoretically should work if the  gazebo_ros_control (libgazebo_ros_control.so) plug in is used in Gazebo but there is a note that the hardware_interface::VelocityJointInterface is not fully implemented.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277415/use-of-diff_drive_controller-to-simulate-a-differential-drive-in-gazebo/) by [Toma Tacescu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32884/toma-tacescu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-12-06**:
Works for me, do you have any specific question?

**Comment by [Toma Tacescu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32884/toma-tacescu/) on 2017-12-06**:
It is not necessary to implement RobotHWSim, it works using just the Gazebo plugin, correct? Do you know  of any robot sample that have implemented this configuration?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-12-06**:
libgazebo_ros_control with DefaultRobotHWSim should do.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-12-06**:
As an example I would only have mine atm: [launch-](https://github.com/nxdefiant/ros_wild_thumper/blob/master/launch/gazebo.launch), [urdf-](https://github.com/nxdefiant/ros_wild_thumper/blob/master/urdf/wild_thumper.urdf.xacro) file.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-12-06**:
[Husky](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Husky) might use it.

**Comment by [Toma Tacescu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32884/toma-tacescu/) on 2017-12-06**:
Thank you! I really appreciate your feedback!

**Comment by [Toma Tacescu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32884/toma-tacescu/) on 2017-12-06**:
Do you also use the diff_drive_controller on the real robot? I was looking at the links from your repository and could not find the diff_drive_controller implemented on the hardware robot.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-12-06**:
No, only simulation, "real" odometry calculation is done on a separate real time cpu

**Comment by [Toma Tacescu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32884/toma-tacescu/) on 2017-12-09**:
Did you encounter this error: "Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface". I am getting it when I run my launch file your "gazebo.launch"

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-12-09**:
You should open a new question for this with your launch files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Humpelstilzchen thank you for your help! It works and your suggestions helped a lot!

Here are some of the key steps that may help others:

- in the robot model need to use
- in the robot model need SimpleTransmission reference
- in the robot model inertia values exported from CAD do not always work
- orientation of the robot is not always exported correctly from CAD (X axis forward)
- need to setup diff_drive_controller.yaml parameters (these worked for me: http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller)
- need to run the controller_spawner node:
- I had to be very specific with the name space

---

Originally posted by [Toma Tacescu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32884/toma-tacescu/) with karma: 36 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0